# How do I pass html based on ruby code / erb into a method expecting a string in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code doesn't work because I can't access the helper inside of a controller:

```
string << "#{has shared link_to @review.title, @review}"
```

But within the action (or possibly a method in the model) I still need to pass the html that would be generated from this.

I tried the template instance but doesn't work in Rails 3

Comment: How do I do that in a controller?

Comment: Well, the whole point is not to do it in the controller. Why do you need to generate this in the controller? Aren't you showing it in a view? Creating a helper method gives you something you can easily call in whatever view is showing this string.

Comment: I'm not showing it in a view -- I am sending it to a external web-service....maybe I should just hand-code it....

Answer (score 0):

Just as a basic example, say you have:

app/messages_controller.rb  and

helper/messages_helper.rb

In you messages_helper.rb you may have something like what you've suggested.

```
#Also you should use = instead of <<
#You can only use << on a variable that has already been initialised
#a =  "hello "  #=> "hello"
#a << "world"   #=> "hello world"
#b << "whatevs" #=> ERROR

def dummy_helper_method
    @html_string = "has shared #{link_to @review.title, @review}"
    @html_string
end
```

Then in your messages_controller.rb in any of your methods you can call your new dummy_method and you'll now get access to your @html_string instance variable

```
def index
    dummy_helper_method

    #you can now access your @html_string variable from inside this index method
end
```

**Just as a note though, this isn't the right way to do this**. You shouldn't call it in your controller unless you're trying to do something fairly specific with it which it doesn't look like you are. If you're trying to get it out into your view so that you can display it, you can actually call your helper method that you've just created in any of your messages' view files (views/messages/anything_in_here.html.erb) rather than calling it in your controller.

For example:

```
#views/messages/edit.html.erb
<%= dummy_helper_method %>
```

Anyways, hope it helps

Comment: if I call the dummy_helper_method, would I then do update_network(@html_string)?

Comment: yeah.. if that's the name of a private method or something that you're using.. I'm not sure I completely understand what you're doing.. But try putting a break point in your controller and seeing what you have

Comment: I don't think the helpers like #{link_to}

Comment: Helpers can definitely handle link_to. I think if you're still having problems it may be because you're using << I had just assumed you've already initialised that variable first. But try it again using = to initialise the variable first. I'll update the above to show you what I mean

Comment: great, thanks, I'll check it out...I actually did initialize it with string = []....let me see what happens.

Comment: :) if you do string = [] you're actually initialising an array, not a string. If you want to initialise a blank string try string = " "

Comment: @2potatocakes...how do I feed the output of the helper into a method, can I do client.update_network(@html_string)?

Comment: Hi @2potatocakes --- it doesn't look like the helper is seen in my controller, I get an unknown method :(  maybe it's not a helper?  What other structures allow me to moduularize things that run in the controller?